# How to loop my question? Javascript Number Guessing Game

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop, numbers

New programmer here - I am trying to create a number guessing game. 
If I guess too high, it tells me "Too high, guess again."
If I guess too low, it tells me "Too low, guess again."
If I guess correct it tells me correct.
But I can only guess 1 wrong answer in each direction.
I have searched and searched and tried almost everything (if/else/while)

I know this is probably a simple fix for experienced programmers.
Please help.
Thanks ---

```
var secretNumber = 53;

var guess = prompt('Guess a number');


if (guess == (53)) {
alert("Yes you got it! 53 is the right answer!")}

while (guess < (53)) {
var guess = prompt('Too Low, Guess again');
}

while (guess > (53)) {
var guess = prompt('Too High, Guess again');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var secretNumber = 53;

var high = false;
var low = false;
var done = false;

var guess = prompt('Guess a number');
while (!done) {
  if (guess === secretNumber) {
    alert("Yes you got it! " + secretNumber + " is the right answer!");
    done = true;
  } else if (guess < secretNumber) {
    if (low) {
      alert('You have failed');
      done = true;
    } else {
      low = true;
      guess = prompt('Too Low, Guess again');
    }
  } else if (guess > secretNumber) {
    if (high) {
      alert('You have failed');
      done = true;
    } else {
      high = true;
      guess = prompt('Too High, Guess again');
    }
  }
}
```

It is not optimal but for this exercise should do.